# What is causing Passenger to throw this error "Cannot disable sole enabled process in group because spawning is not allowed ..."?

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ubuntu-12.04, passenger, out-of-band

All of a sudden, my nginx error log is full of this error message

> [ 2013-10-31 22:56:41.2124 19959/7ff254aae700 Pool2/Group.h:964 ]: Cannot disable sole enabled process in group /app/current#default because spawning is not allowed according to the current configuration options

Here `/app/current` is the folder in which my rails application is located (it is the `Rails.root`)

This error message is most likely coming from line 962 of [this Phusion Passenger source file](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/blob/master/ext/common/ApplicationPool2/Group.h#L962)

One of my production app instance froze. I am suspecting this error is the reason.

I am not sure which `configuration option` is being referenced here. How do I fix this error?

This application was running fine for months now on the same setup. I just upgraded passenger to 4.0.20 last week.

**Update:**

I am using OOB. Here are my passenger configuration

```
 passenger_root /usr/local/rubies/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.20;
 passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby_tuned;
 passenger_max_pool_size 6;
 passenger_spawn_method smart-lv2;
 passenger_buffer_response on;
 passenger_min_instances 5;
 passenger_max_instances_per_app 0;
 passenger_pool_idle_time 180;
 passenger_max_requests 20;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably using [out-of-band work](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_out_of_band_work_and_out_of_band_garbage_collection) but with the wrong configuration. From the manual:

> "Ensure that passenger_max_pool_size and passenger_min_instances are both larger than 1. Out-of-band work only works if there are at least 2 application processes."

Comment: The manual says `passenger_max_instances` is available only in the Enterprise Edition. Unfortunately I am on the OSS edition. Does this mean I cannot use OOB? I have updated the question with my passenger configs.

Comment: Oops, looks like there is an error in the manual. That should be `min_instances` (which is available in the open source version), not `max_instances`. :) I'll fix this.

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood your comment. I am already specifying `min_instances`. What else could be the cause?

Comment: If you were already using `min_instances` then this error may be temporary, non-fatal and safe to ignore. Because I see that you're also using `max_requests`. If a lot of your processes happen to be reaching the `max_requests` limit at the same time, then they will be shut down simultaneously. While they are being restarted, there is a small time window during which there is only one process, and during that time window it is not possible to execute out-of-band GC, hence the message. You can check whether `max_requests` is the cause by disabling it.

Comment: Will check with max_requests disabled. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Yes. commenting out `max_requests` stops the error message. I guess the numbers I am using for pool_size are too low for my needs. Have bumped it up a bit and now things look normal again. Thanks.